# Zoomable element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to do zoomable element in React. I have a list of pictures and I'd like to show bigger picture and info on a click on every picture. On second click anywhere I'd like to zoom out. But how to do this effect in React?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoomable-image check this out

Comment: It would be okay, but I need to add info from API to every picture if it is zoomed in.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds more like a **modal window**. I mean, you don't want to zoom into a detail, but show a bigger full image?
In that case, you could use a **Bootsrap Modal**, check [demo here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/):

You can make this with just React. But installing [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) will save you a lot of time.

**Edit: Make a Modal react component**

Create a Modal component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Modal, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

const ModalWindow = ({showModal, onHideModal, image}) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={showModal}
           onHide={onHideModal}
           image={image}>

          <Modal.Body>
             // Put your image and info here
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
              // Close modal
              <Button onClick={onHideModal}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>

        </Modal>
  );
}

export default ModalWindow;
```

And then pass your image as props

```
<ModalWindow 
    image={//Your image here}
    showModal={//True or false} 
    onHideModal={//Callback function to close modal}/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it what I needed. But after testing I found some problems. One modal works perfect, but 20 modals are changing background to black and it works really slow.

Comment: You don't have to load 20 modals, you can make a react modal component and pass the image and any additional info as props